# Examples of sequential compact sets

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

A subset $S$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is said to be sequentially compact
if every sequence of points of $S$ has a subsequence that converges to a
point of $S$

I want to see some examples of sequentially compact sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$, both trivial and non-trivial as I am having a hard time visualizing them. Thank You

Edit: As pointed out, all the three definitions are equivalent in $\mathbb{R}^n$, I want to see some examples of sequentially compact set in maybe some other topological space where they are not always the same.

Comment: In $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the natural topology (i.e. seen as a metric space), sequentially compact is equivalent to compact, which is equivalent to closed and bounded.

Comment: In metric spaces, sequentially compact is equivalent to compact, but not to closed and bounded. For example, in $(\mathbb{Q},|.|)$, the set $[0,1]\cap \mathbb{Q}$ is closed and bounded, but not compact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a complete metric space, a subset  $K\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is sequentially compact, if, and only if, is closed and bounded. So you can think of closed balls of any radius, finite sets, closures of bounded sets. Any finite union of such sets will also be sequentially compact, because they will still be bounded and closed.

Comment: If you remove the 'As $\mathbb R^n$ is a metric space' from the beginning, then this is true. Or replace with 'As $\mathbb R^n$ is a *locally compact* metric space'.

Answer (score 0):

There exists a website for topological counterexamples : [$\pi$-Base](https://topology.pi-base.org/)

1. [Examples of sequentially compact spaces but not compact.](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=Sequentially%20Compact%20%26%20%7ECompact)
2. [Examples of compact spaces but not sequentially compact.](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=%7ESequentially%20Compact%20%26%20Compact)

Notice you can characterise compactness in terms of sequences but you have to consider sequences indexed by larger ordinals than $\omega$. See [Nets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_(mathematics)) or [Filters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filters_in_topology).